# how to insert text with sql query into a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Please help me to insert simple sql query into table for example:

insert into table0 ( sql_text) values ( 'select count(*) from table1;');

I am receiving error .

Thanks,

Comment: At least include the error message in your question

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Comment: What is your table structure?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) values ('Select count(*) from tableName; ');
```